# RDLC gathering and presenting data

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

Recently got back into programming after a few years break, and am in the process of building a POS(Point of Sale) software app for my own consumption. I though the app was pretty near close to Version 1 Beta release ..... until I ran into the Reporting side of things.

Having trolled through numerous Tutorials and Walkthroughs, I am pretty much none the wiser as to how to achieve what I need the report to do.

What I am trying to achieve is an EOD (End of Day) report and the issue that I am running into is how to present the data that comes from 4 different queries.

I have tried the Business object approach and this works for the first level that is set up at design time, but the remainder return nothing.

Is there a better approach (easier to get my head around) to achieve this?
Could someone recommend a tutorial/Walkthrough that models a report using data from different objects or tables?
Extract fronm Code 
Reportviewer form with docked reportviewer

```
 public partial class ReportViewer : Form
{

    private List<VO.TotSalesByDept> deptSales = new List<VO.TotSalesByDept>();
    private VO.TotalSales daySales = new VO.TotalSales();
    private List<VO.TotSalesByTender> tendSales = new List<VO.TotSalesByTender>();
    private List<VO.TotSalesByGroup> grpSales = new List<VO.TotSalesByGroup>();

    private BUS.UserBUS _userBUS = new BUS.UserBUS();

    public ReportViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //daySales = _userBUS.getSalesTot(DateTime.Now);

        deptSales = _userBUS.getDeptSales(DateTime.Now);
        //tendSales = _userBUS.getTendSales(DateTime.Now);
        //grpSales = _userBUS.getGroupSales(DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);

        //this.TotalSalesBindingSource.DataSource = daySales ;
        //this.TotSalesByGrp.DataSource = grpSales;
        //this.TotSalesByTender.DataSource = tendSales;
        this.TotSalesByDeptBindingSource.DataSource = deptSales;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    //private void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    e.DataSources.Clear();
    //    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource());
    //}


}
```

The business layer that  the form calls

```
 public List<VO.TotSalesByDept> getDeptSales(DateTime _now)
    {
        List<VO.TotSalesByDept> deptSales = new List<VO.TotSalesByDept>();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable = _userDAO.getTSalesByDept(_now.Date);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            VO.TotSalesByDept deptSale = new VO.TotSalesByDept();
            deptSale.Dept = dr["Department"].ToString();
            deptSale.RepQty = Int32.Parse(dr["Total QTY"].ToString());
            deptSale.RGSales = decimal.Round(decimal.Parse(dr["TotItemSales"].ToString()),2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

            deptSales.Add(deptSale);
        }
        return deptSales;
    }
```

not sure what else you would need to see?
Many thanks in advance
Steve

Comment: The question is too generic , show us what you have tried.

Comment: Post updated - thank you for your responce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link enabled me to begin working on a solution

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx

Thanks
Steve